# Periodic Solution of Ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Consider the homogeneous equation $ y'+a(x) y=0$, a is with period $\xi$ and continuous on $-\infty<x<\infty$.

(a) Show that there exist a constant c such that $y(x+\xi)=cy(x)$ for all x and 
$$c=exp \left(- \int_0^\xi \ a(t) dt \right) $$

(b) What condition must 'a' satisfy in order that there a exist a non- trivial solution of period $\xi$, of period $2\xi$? If 'a' is real valued, what is the condition?

(c) If a is constant, what must this constant be in order that a non-trivial solution of period 2$\xi$ exists ?

I have made an attempt at (a) but its leading to redundancy i think its time to ask for some help. Please help me if you can Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do part a, use integrating factors: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor

Comment: it seems i have used the method where a is constant to this i will change and tried again got it great thanks for the hint

Comment: any chance you can guide me on part b and c i am real bad with periodic stuff Thanks

Comment: For part b, $y$ is $\xi$ periodic if and only if $c=1$, and $2\xi$ periodic if and only if $c^2 = 1$.  No deep knowledge about periodic functions is required - just use the definition.

Comment: OK, one fact will be helpful.  If $a$ is $\xi$ periodic, then $\int_0^\xi a(t) \, dt = \int_x^{x+\xi} a(t) \, dt$.

Comment: I get the first bit c=1 but why $c^2=1$ i dont get and what can i do about it being real valued and If a is constant it must be 2 to get 2$\xi$ to be the period of y am i correct Thanks

Comment: If $c=1$, then you need $\int_0^\xi a(t) \, dt$ to be a multiple of $2\pi i$.  If $a$ is real valued, it must be zero.

Comment: If $y$ is $2\xi$ periodic, you use $y(x+2\xi) = c y(x+\xi) = c^2 y(x)$.

Comment: If $a$ is constant, then $\int_0^\xi a(t) dt = a\xi$, and simply apply what you just did.

Comment: awesome help got it Thanks